# Linux x86 syscall 355 is run repeatedly on bootup and causes crash unless returns -ENOSYS

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86, system-calls

kernel version: 3.14.33

Before I added any system calls, the highest-numbered one for x86 (32 bit) was 352.  I then added 353-357 by simply adding a row each to arch/x86/syscall/syscall_32.tbl  and then using SYSCALL_DEFINEx as appropriate in kernel/*.

The problem is with the syscall numbered 355.  It is run repeatedly on bootup and when it doesn't directly return -ENOSYS, it crashes the kernel on bootup with a failed assertion in systemd (sd_id128_randomize() returns < 0).  When 355 returns -ENOSYS directly, the system boots fine.

Is there another step I need to take to "officially" install the syscall?  Like increment some max number?  Is 355 reserved for something that I'm totally screwing up?

I managed to work around by simply skipping 355, so I'm very sure it's not a bug in my syscall implementation

Comment: Just curious, why are you implementing a new syscall? If this isn't a learning exercise, you should know that 99.99% of the time, making a new syscall is the wrong way to do whatever you want to do. It shouldn't be taken lightly.

Comment: can you provide a patch so people can test and solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that more recent versions of kernel include additional system calls, with 355 being `getrandom()`. systemd pokes at this system call number to see if the running kernel has a builtin randomizer, and if the return is not ENOSYS, it thinks the syscall is getrandom() and something would probably go wrong.

References:
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl
http://lwn.net/Articles/606141/